# Plot the spatial join shapefile boundary in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, spatial-join, geopandas

I have two spatial object

`Geo_TWS` is a shapefile boundary, `geo_cell` is points and already convert to GeoPandas.

`base = Geo_TWS.plot(color='white', edgecolor='black')
 geo_cell.plot(ax = base,color='yellow' )`
[image]

My problem is: how can I plot the yellow points with the intersects black boundary?

So the final figure shows the yellow shape, and the black boundary line within the shape.

(I have tried `gpd.sjoin` but seems can't complete it, anyone have better ideas? or proper way to use `gpd.sjoin`)

**Attempt:**

```
import geopandas as gpd

TWS = gpd.read_file('TWP bounadry/TownBoundary2.shp')
TWS = TWS.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
Geo_TWS = TWS
```

[image]

```
#cell file
import pandas as pd

grid_cell = pd.read_csv('ARB_2km_Info.txt', delim_whitespace=True)


from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point


#map to point
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(grid_cell.Lon, grid_cell.Lat)]
new = grid_cell.drop(['Lon', 'Lat'], axis=1)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
geo_cell = GeoDataFrame(new, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

[image]

```
Twship_in_cell = gpd.sjoin(Geo_TWS, geo_cell,  how="left", op='intersects')

Twship_in_cell.plot(color = 'white', edgecolor = 'black')
```

[image]

I have tried many `how` and `op` combinations, but still not working, and thats the problem..

Comment: Please show the code that you tried with `sjoin`. And ideally provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try the `sjoin` with the dataframes swapped. The spatial join will keep the geometry of the left dataframe (and in fact, in your example, you'll have one polygon being drawn for every point that was intersected).

Comment: If you just want to select those points inside the polygon (and not merge any other columns), you can do boolean filtering using `geo_cell[geo_cell.geometry.within(polygon)]`, where `polygon = Geo_TWS.geometry[0]`

Comment: @om_henners nope, it can't work either, even swap and use the points index still can't retrieve the boundary line within the cells area.

Comment: @joris actually i want to select the shapefile(polygon)  boundary within the points area. not points within polygon, but where polygon within the points, and get the within polygon boundary line.

Comment: @wflwo It is completely unclear what you *exactly* want. Show some actual data: make a few points and a polygon with code to illustrate it, and create the result you would want for those illustrative data.